# Using a function and an condition to fill up one dataframe column to another dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have  two dataframes like below ,
df1 and df2 has many columns , reduced it for better readability

```
        df1                   df2 
   id   A    B    C        ID   A        
    1   x    y    z         1   m1      
    2   x1   y1   z1        2   m2     
    3   x2   y2   z2
```

Requirement is to fill up column A of df2  using a function where df1.id == df2.ID , lets this function be function1

```
input function1(x,y,z)     output    return m1. 
input function1(x1,y1,z1)  output    return m2.
```

basically I have to use the function1 to fill the column A in df2 and where df1.id == df2.ID , in the function i have to send out the values from the 3 columns of df1

I was trying like below

```
df2['A'] = df1.loc[df1['id'] == df2['ID'],function1(df1['A'],df1['B'],df1['C'])]
```

but its not working , obviously function is not designed for columns as input ,  any suggestions?

Comment: Your question is confusing, can you please provide a sample of your expected output? This sounds like a merge or a join, or possibly `.apply()`, but it's not clear

Comment: basically I have to use the function to fill the column A in df2 and where df1.id == df2.ID , in the function i have to send out the values from the 3 columns of df1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i solved it , I created a new column in df1

```
df1["NewCol"] = df1.apply(lambda x: function1(df1['A'],df1['B'],df1['C']))
```

and 
then implemented in df2

```
df2['A'] = df1.loc[df1['id'] == df2['ID'], "NewCol"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking my best shot based on my understanding of your problem:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'id': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3},
 'A': {0: 'x', 1: 'x1', 2: 'x2'},
 'B': {0: 'y', 1: 'y1', 2: 'y2'},
 'C': {0: 'z', 1: 'z1', 2: 'z2'}})

df2=pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2]})

def my_func(a,b,c):#in your case, function1
    if all('1' in i for i in (a,b,c)):
        return 'm2'
    else:
        return 'm1'

df2['A']=df1[df1['id'].isin(df2['ID'])]\#find where the id columns match
.apply(lambda x: my_func(*x[1:]), axis=1)#apply the function on the A,B,C columns of df1

df2

    ID  A
0   1   m1
1   2   m2
```

Comment: what if df1 has more than three columns , and other columns does not matter anyway , what will be the change for this part my_func(*x[1:])

Comment: Whatever the slice of columns is that your function uses, that would be the slice `x[2:]`, `x[1:4]` etc. Or you can subset the dataframe first, like `df1[['A','B','C']]`

Comment: its not working , function is not accepting ,  missing 2 required positional arguments

Comment: It seems like you need to [edit] your original post with an actual [mcve] showing accurate sample data of your input dataframe(s), the code (or approximate code) of your `function1`, and a sample of your expected output according to [How to make good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples). It's very difficult to know how to help if we have to guess.